# Terminal freezes when I run the following C++ code and I am not sure why?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am learning C++ and multifile implementation of C++. So, I have created 3 files: the header, the implementaion and the main. All of them compile fine (in Mac OSX terminal) but when it run the output file a.out, nothing shows, and after a while, the terminal stops responding. Then the entire system stops responding and the only way I can access the system again is by doing a forced shutdown. If anyone could provide any insight on resolving this issue, I would really appreciate it.

I used

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -o Cube.o Cube.cpp
```

to compile the files and
`g++ main.o Cube.o` to link the files.

Header:

```
#pragma once
class Cube{
    public:
        double getVolume();
        double getSurfaceArea();
        void setLength(double lenth);
    private:
        double length_;
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "Cube.h"

double Cube::getVolume(){
    return length_ * length_ * length_;
    }

double Cube::getSurfaceArea(){
    return 6 * length_ * length_;
    }
 void Cube::setLength(double length){
     length_ = length;
     }
```

Main:

```
#include "Cube.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    Cube c;

    c.setLength(4.0);

    double volume = c.getVolume();
    double surfaceArea = c.getSurfaceArea();
    std::cout << "Volume" << volume << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Surface Area" << surfaceArea << std::endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Having copied your exact code into an Alpine Linux terminal running under WSLv2, compiled exactly as described with g++ version `(Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203`, it works as expected, no problems, no warnings, just `Volume64` and `Surface Area96` as output. There's nothing wrong with the code that I can see; the fact your whole OS is freezing makes me suspect something is terribly wrong with your installation unrelated to this program, but perhaps triggered by it in some arcane way.

Comment: one minor warning: always include system headers (iostream for example) first so that static-storage-duration elements are initialized properly. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44613079/9106728).

Comment: @SauravYadav I dont see that being the point of the answer you linked. I think that answer is more about don't use static storage duration members in the construction of other static storage duration members, because you cannot be sure which is initialised first.